# jQuery datatables width keeps resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datatables

I'm using jquery [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) to add functionality to my HTML table. I want to set the width to a fixed % value. It works, but whenever I change the "Show x entries" dropdown which changes the number of entries to display on the change, the width resets. How can I stop this reset?

EDIT: I think this happens when certain td elements are really large (300+ characters). Not sure how to fix this though

Html (using angularjs framework, though that shouldn't matter):

```
    <table ng-if="itms && itms.length > 0" id="my-table" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>c1</th>
            <th>c2</th>
            <th>c3</th>
            <th>c4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>c1</th>
            <th>c2</th>
            <th>c3</th>
            <th>c4</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="itm in itms track by $index" repeat-done>
            <td>{{itm.c1}}</td>
            <td>{{itm.c2}}</td>
            <td>{{itm.c3}}</td>
            <td>{{itm.c4}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#my-table').DataTable({
    "autoWidth": false,
    "columns": [
        {"width": "20%"},
        {"width": "5%"},
        {"width": "25%"},
        {"width": "50%"}
    ]
});
```

directive js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('repeatDone', function($timeout) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $timeout(callback1);
        }
}
});
function callback1(){
    $('#my-table').DataTable({
    "autoWidth": false,
    "columns": [
        {"width": "20%"},
        {"width": "5%"},
        {"width": "25%"},
        {"width": "50%"}
    ]
});
```